# MongoDB - Help needed to make some aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I am having a bad time trying to do an aggregation in MongoDB.

I need to cross some infos from each user and as a final result I want a list of users (where there is only one object for each user) and for each object there is some lists with distinct information.

1 - The `createdAtList` array must be ordered from the oldest to the newest date. The `sumOfTotal` means the current position `total` summed up with the previous `sumOfTotal` (Exemplified in the code below), not just the sum of the `total's`

2 - The `categotyList` must be ordered like: `category1, category2, category3 ...`

3 - The desired final result must be ordered like: `user1, user2, user3 ...`

Basically I need some help to do the following:

```
//List of docs from my collection:
[
    {
        _id: "doc1",
        user: "user1",
        category: "category1",
        createdAt: "2018-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        _id: "doc2",
        user: "user1",
        category: "category2",
        createdAt: "2017-12-12T00:00:00.000Z",
    },
    {
        _id: "doc3",
        user: "user1",
        category: "category1",
        createdAt: "2017-12-12T00:00:00.000Z",
    },
    {
        _id: "doc4",
        user: "user1",
        category: "category2",
        createdAt: "2018-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        _id: "doc5",
        user: "user1",
        category: "category3",
        createdAt: "2017-11-11T00:00:00.000Z"
    }
]

//Desired result:
{
    user: "user1",
    createdAtList: [ //list ordered by createdAt
        {
            createdAt: "2017-11-11T00:00:00.000Z",
            total: 1,
            sumOfTotal: 0
        }
        {
            createdAt: "2017-12-12T00:00:00.000Z",
            total: 2,
            sumOfTotal: 3 //summed up with the previous
        }
        {
            createdAt: "2018-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
            total: 2,
            sumOfTotal: 5 //summed up with the previous
        }
    ],
    categotyList: [ //list ordered by category
        {
            category: "category1",
            total: 2
        },
        {
            category: "category2",
            total: 2
        },
        {
            category: "category3",
            total: 1
        }
    ]
},
...
```

Is possible to do this in the same aggregate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think it really makes sense to have the createdAtList.sumOfTotal field.  I do not think the fields in an array should be dependent upon a particular order of the elements.  If you want some field to contain the sum of the createdAtList.total field, I think there should only be one field (outside of the array).  That being said, here is the query I came up with to give you the desired results (using "users" as the name of the collection):

```
db.users.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                user: "$user",
                createdAt: "$createdAt"
            },
            total: { $sum: 1 },
            category: { $push: "$category" }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            user: "$_id.user",
            createdAt: "$_id.createdAt",
            total: "$total",
            category: 1
        }
    },
    { $unwind: "$category" },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                user: "$user",
                category: "$category"
            },
            catTotal: { $sum: 1 },
            createdAtList: {
                $push: {
                    createdAt: "$createdAt",
                    total: "$total"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            user: "$_id.user",
            createdAtList: 1,
            category: "$_id.category",
            catTotal: 1
        }
    },
    { $unwind: "$createdAtList" },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$user",
            createdAtList: {
                $addToSet: "$createdAtList"
            },
            categoryList: {
                $addToSet: {
                    category: "$category",
                    total: "$catTotal"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    { $unwind: "$createdAtList" },
    { $sort: { "createdAtList.createdAt": 1 } },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id",
            createdAtList: {
                $push: "$createdAtList"
            },
            categoryList: {
                $first: "$categoryList"
            }
        }
    },
    { $unwind: "$categoryList" },
    { $sort: { "categoryList.category": 1 } },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id",
            createdAtList: {
                $first: "$createdAtList"
            },
            categoryList: {
                $push: "$categoryList"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
        _id: 0,
        user: "$_id",
        createdAtList: 1,
        sumOfTotal: { $sum: "$createdAtList.total" },
        categoryList: 1
        }
    },
    { $sort: { user: 1 } },
]).pretty()
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping. Your solution worked very well. However, I edited my question and tried to explain better what I was trying to do with the `sumOfTotal`. Moreover the `createdAtList`, `categoryList` and the final result must be ordered. Please see the edit.

Comment: I understood what you were trying to do with the sumOfTotal, but I still don't think it's a good design to do something like that. Typically, an array should be agnostic to the order. I did already sort the categoryId, but I will plan to edit the other sorts and attempt to do the sumOfTotal as specified. I am away from home at the moment

Comment: So, you are right about the `sumOfTotal`, don't worry about it. I can do it easily on the JS having the `createdAtList` ordered. Thank you once again.

Comment: I edited the query as requested.  Unless I'm loosing my mind, you changed the name of the userId field and the categoryId field to user and category, respectively.  I also updated my answer to reflect this change.

Comment: Hi. Just giving you a feedback. It worked very well. Thank you for helping me out and you are not loosing your mind, I have changed the properties name, hahaha.